# Edit a script I found to import a list of adusers, grab their info and export back to another csv

Tags: powershell, csv

All I am needing assistance with a project.  My goal is to use powershell to search for a user and report back what groups they belong to.

I took the script http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1872-get-user-group-memberships to meet my initial needs.

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeLine=$true)]
    [Alias("ID","Users","Name")]
    [string[]]$User
)
Begin {
    Try { Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop }
    Catch { Write-Host "Unable to load Active Directory module, is RSAT installed?"; Break }
}

Process {
    ForEach ($U in $User)
    {   $UN = Get-ADUser $U -Properties MemberOf
        $Groups = ForEach ($Group in ($UN.MemberOf))
        {   (Get-ADGroup $Group).Name
        } 
        $Groups = $Groups | Sort
        ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
        {   New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Name = $UN.Name
                Group = $Group
            } |  export-csv "c:\grouptest.csv" -append
        } 
    } 
}
```

I was even able to get it to export the results. By adding the export-csv command.  Here is where I am running into an issue.  I do not know what to change to it grab the input from a csv and then export those results to a different csv.

SO I want to add the command $UserList=IMPORT-CSV C:\Userlist.csv

I tried this.

```
Begin {
    Try { Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop }
    Catch { Write-Host "Unable to load Active Directory module, is RSAT installed?"; Break }
}

Process {
$UserList=IMPORT-CSV C:\Userlist.csv
    ForEach ($U in $UserList)
    {   $UN = Get-ADUser $U -Properties MemberOf
        $Groups = ForEach ($Group in ($UN.MemberOf))
        {   (Get-ADGroup $Group).Name
        } 
        $Groups = $Groups | Sort
        ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
        {   New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Name = $UN.Name
                Group = $Group
            } |  export-csv "c:\grouptest.csv" -append
        } 
    } 
}
```

But I keep getting an error.  It looks like it is trying to combine the first user with all the other users to make a name.

Any help would be appericated. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the results of your foreach loop to a variable, and then move the Export-Csv to the end of the foreach. As it is, you're overwriting the csv with each iteration through the loop.

```
Begin {
    Try { Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop }
    Catch { Write-Host "Unable to load Active Directory module, is RSAT installed?"; Break }
}

Process {
    $UserList=IMPORT-CSV C:\Userlist.csv
    $users = ForEach ($U in $UserList)
    {   $UN = Get-ADUser $U -Properties MemberOf
        $Groups = ForEach ($Group in ($UN.MemberOf))
        {   (Get-ADGroup $Group).Name
        } 
        $Groups = $Groups | Sort
        ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
        {   New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Name = $UN.Name
                Group = $Group
            } 
        } 
    } 
    $users | export-csv "c:\grouptest.csv" -append
}
```

Comment: I copied your edited script and tried to run it.  I got the error Get-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "@{arnett=ahudson}" to type
"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser". Error: "Cannot convert the "@{arnett=ahudson}" value of type
"System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to   type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser"."
The very interesting part about this is that arnett is the first user in the list and ahudson is the second user.  For each proceeding error the @{arnett is the same, but the = is the next user in the list.

Comment: Import-CSV imports the contents as an array of objects, using the first row as the headers. If there's only the user name on each line, change Import-CSV to Get-Content. If not, post an excerpt of UserList.csv.

Comment: Perfect the Get-Content worked.   I will post my working code a little later.  Now to try to figure out if the user ID is the same how to keep the groups in the same row, just add to a new column. However thats just being fancy.  This gives me what I need for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working script for someone else who might need such a thing.

```
Begin {
Try { Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop }
Catch { Write-Host "Unable to load Active Directory module, is RSAT installed?"; Break }
}

Process {
$UserList=Get-Content C:\Userlist.csv
$users = ForEach ($U in $UserList)
{   $UN = Get-ADUser $U -Properties MemberOf
    $Groups = ForEach ($Group in ($UN.MemberOf))
    {   (Get-ADGroup $Group).Name
    } 
    $Groups = $Groups | Sort
    ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
    {   New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Name = $UN.Name
            Group = $Group
        } 
    } 
} 
$users | export-csv "c:\grouptest.csv" -append
}
```