# Export-csv: Merge Duplicate Rows

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

All, Thanks to the solution in quesiton [Edit a script I found to import a list of adusers, grab their info and export back to another csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696500/edit-a-script-i-found-to-import-a-list-of-adusers-grab-their-info-and-export-ba/22696777?noredirect=1#22696777) I was able to come up with the following script.  The Script pulls a username from a csv file, connects to ad, and exports the users groups to a different csv.  That part works perfectly.  Here is where I am running into issues.  Each user name/group gets put in a new row.  Which is perfect except for users in multiple groups.  So example

```
ColA     ColB
User     Group
bob      admin 
jeff     domain admin  
jeff     test admin 
jeff     power user
```

What I would like is do is come up with a way export in the following format

```
ColA     ColB           ColC          ColD   
User     Group          Group         Group
bob      admin
jeff     domian admin   test admin    power user
```

Here is my script

```
Begin {
Try { Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop }
Catch { Write-Host "Unable to load Active Directory module, is RSAT installed?"; Break }
}

Process {
$UserList=Get-Content C:\Userlist.csv
$users = ForEach ($U in $UserList)
{   $UN = Get-ADUser $U -Properties MemberOf
$Groups = ForEach ($Group in ($UN.MemberOf))
{   (Get-ADGroup $Group).Name
} 
$Groups = $Groups | Sort
ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
{   New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $UN.Name
        Group = $Group
    } 
} 
} 
$users | export-csv "c:\grouptest.csv" -append
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: I edited the data to try and make my goal more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your goal you simply need to replace this:

```
ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
{   New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $UN.Name
        Group = $Group
    } 
}
```

with this:

```
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Name  = $UN.Name
    Group = $Groups
}
```

Comment: WHen I do that I get the first group only,  but further more it gives me the full Distinguished name at well.

Comment: @sjustice `$Group` should've been `$Groups`. Other than that the code worked when I tested it. You could `-join` the elements of the array `$Groups` if you want the property `Group` to be a single string, though.

Comment: Thanks I went back and worked on that.  I did get it to work.  Work the same way you did is questionable.  : )  What I got was a spreadsheet that only had one group per user,  regardless of if they had multiple groups or not.  However I think your -join command is on the right path of where I really want to be.  I will let you know where I get with that.  I don't know if you saw it, but I edited my orginal post to try and explain better what I as after.

Comment: I don't think I am going to be able to get this where I want it at this point.  Working on the logic it would appear this is what I have to do.  Compare the current user with the previous user.  If user exists check to see if col-group1 is null if not go to next column else paste.  That all seems simple logic, but there are things that I have not figured out yet.  1. How to store the previous user for comparrison and how to know what row to be in when I do the col-group comparrison.   I am running out of time to get my project done so I will have to stop for the time being.